# Video capture of application window

Tags: software-recommendation, window, screencast, desktop-recording

I need to do a video capture of just a running application window, not the entire desktop.

Similar to the Nvidia Games Bar functionality in Windows.
Is there a 3rd party app that will do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[**VokoscreenNG**](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreenNG) offers an option to record a window:

[image]

You can install it as a snap package by running the following command in Terminal

```
snap install vokoscreen-ng
```

You can also install it with `apt` on Ubuntu 20.04 and later from the [universe repo](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/480481) by running

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen-ng
```